# VBA Range.Replace does not work second time

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I am very new in VBA. I created 2 buttons. Buttons are just for changing the sheets where the data in the cells come from. For example, I pull the numbers from sheet "ecommerce(D2C)" and when I click the button SaaS, it will pull the data from sheet "SaaS". And for Ecommerce button vice versa. I simply used Range.Raplace method for this. But the problem, SaaS button works, taking the numbers from sheet "SaaS", but when I click Ecommerce, it doesn't change the numbers back from "SaaS" sheet to "Ecommerce" sheet. I would be glad if you can help me with this issue. I don't know where I am making the mistake since I am using almost the same code for both of them.

````
Sub SaaS()

Cells.Select
Selection.Replace What:="ecommerce(D2C)", Replacement:="SaaS", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Range("A1").Select

End Sub

Sub Ecommerce()

Cells.Select
Selection.Replace What:="SaaS", Replacement:="ecommerce(D2C)", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Range("A2").Select

End Sub ```
````

Comment: I ran your code in my computer and both Subs are working as they should: they replaces all occurrences of the text "ecommerce(D2C)" into "SaaS" and vice-versa. I'm not sure if I understood exactly what you're trying to achieve... because the Replace method just replaces text, and won't move numbers from one sheet to another. Can you please try to elaborate a little more on your question?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! I am not trying to move. I have total 3 sheets, one is SaaS, the other one is Ecommerce and the third one is the sheet where I work with the numbers in SaaS and Ecommerce sheets. For example in the third sheet I am taking the numbers from sheet "SaaS" so the formula will be "=SaaS!B3". With these buttons that I created, when I click the Ecommerce button for example, I wanna replace the "SaaS" in the formula with "Ecommerce", so the cells will take the data from "Ecommerce" sheet. It works for SaaS buttons, but it doesn't work for Ecommerce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I could reproduce the behaviour you was getting. What I had to do is to change from `ecommerce(D2C)` to `Ecommerce` (considering that this is the worksheet name). If you try to use the `Replace` method with something that would result in an incorrect formula, it just does nothing.

```
Sub SaaS()

    Cells.Select
    Selection.Replace What:="Ecommerce", Replacement:="SaaS", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub

Sub Ecommerce()

    Cells.Select
    Selection.Replace What:="SaaS", Replacement:="Ecommerce", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
    Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This method is failing for "ecommerce(D2C)" because Excel requires you to put a sheet name of this type within single quotes for use in a formula: e.g. `"='ecommerce(D2C)'!A1"`.

Once you click the "Saas" button, this becomes `"='SaaS'!A1"`, but that one does not require the single quotes, so that Excel automatically adjusts it to `"=SaaS!A1"`. So, now, when you try to switch it back again, it will fail, because you are asking Excel to create a reference to `"=ecommerce(D2C)!A1"`, and it won't allow that.

Hence, the fix is simple, add two single quotes:

```
Sub Ecommerce()

Cells.Select
Selection.Replace What:="SaaS", Replacement:="'ecommerce(D2C)'", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```